# Vue.js not working on Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, vue.js, asset-pipeline

I've been trying to deploy my Rails + Vue.js app to Heroku. Vue.js works just fine locally, but not on Heroku. I feel I am not doing something with asset pipeline, but can't figure out what.

I am using `vuejs-rails` gem for Vue, here is the full Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Assets
gem 'vuejs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.9"
gem 'dentaku'
gem "browserify-rails"
# Server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rollbar'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

### Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require vue
//= require_tree .
```

I've configured Multiple Heroku Buildpacks as seen in my App.json

### App.json

```
{
  "name": "test_name",
  "description": "Some stuff",
  "addons": [
    "deployhooks",
    "newrelic",
    "rollbar"
  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/nodejs"
    },
    {
      "url": "urn:buildpack:heroku/ruby"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the output when I deploy to Heroku. Doesn't seem like assets:precompile does anything:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 6.x via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.10.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.10
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.0.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Using minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using rack 2.0.1
remote:        Using nio4r 2.0.0
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 7.1.4
remote:        Using public_suffix 2.0.5
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using sass 3.4.23
remote:        Using method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Using thor 0.19.4
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using dentaku 2.0.10
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.7
remote:        Using sexp_processor 4.9.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using pg 0.20.0
remote:        Using puma 3.8.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Using vuejs-rails 2.2.1
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.7.1
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using addressable 2.5.1
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.7.7.2
remote:        Using uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using ruby_parser 3.9.0
remote:        Using haml 4.0.7
remote:        Using rollbar 2.12.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha6
remote:        Using activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.0
remote:        Using activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.6.3
remote:        Using html2haml 2.1.0
remote:        Using actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Using activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Using activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Using actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Using actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Using railties 5.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Using browserify-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using haml-rails 0.9.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Using rails 5.0.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 64 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (2.30s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (1.56s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 44.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v11
remote:        https://nlp-calculator.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Javascript error, specifically, I needed to include Tether to use Bootstrap. On local there is no minification, so even with an error, Vue.js was working. But on Production, one JS error would completely stop the whole application JS compiling.

Making sure I have that dependency fixed the problem.

Comment: For further vue integration on rails, I would recommend checking out `webpacker` project (https://github.com/rails/webpacker) and specifically `rails new app webpack=vue`command in rails 5.1